# Sum between specific dates

Tags: sql

I am simply trying to modify an existing query to add(SUM) the total amount of hours during a week and then push the data to the table if they are over 40. I am a novice when it comes to SQL and I have no idea at this point how to implement this formula. As a side note any good Syntax checkers I can use to help?  This is what I have to modify.

```
 SELECT dbo_Associates.FirstName
    , dbo_Associates.LastName
    , dbo_Events.DATE
    , Sum(dbo_Events.Amount) AS SumOfAmount
FROM (
    dbo_Events INNER JOIN dbo_Associates
        ON dbo_Events.AssociateId = dbo_Associates.Id
    )
INNER JOIN dbo_Categories
    ON dbo_Events.CategoryId = dbo_Categories.Id
WHERE (
        (
            (dbo_Categories.NAME) <> "Sub-Contractor"
            AND (dbo_Categories.NAME) <> "Invoice"
            AND (dbo_Categories.NAME) <> "Receipt"
            AND (dbo_Categories.NAME) <> "Equipment"
            AND (dbo_Categories.NAME) <> "Meetings"
            AND (dbo_Categories.NAME) <> "Comp Time"
            AND (dbo_Categories.NAME) <> "Training"
            AND (dbo_Categories.NAME) <> "Other"
            AND (dbo_Categories.NAME) <> "Overnight Stay (each)"
            )
        )
GROUP BY dbo_Associates.FirstName
    , dbo_Associates.LastName
    , dbo_Events.DATE
    , dbo_Associates.Id
HAVING (
        (
            (dbo_Events.DATE) >= #8 / 31 / 2016 #
            AND (dbo_Events.DATE) <= #9 / 15 / 2016 #
            )
        AND ((Sum(dbo_Events.Amount)) >= 11.25)
        AND (
            (dbo_Associates.Id) <> 17
            AND (dbo_Associates.Id) <> 40
            AND (dbo_Associates.Id) <> 41
            AND (dbo_Associates.Id) <> 44
            AND (dbo_Associates.Id) <> 45
            AND (dbo_Associates.Id) <> 47
            )
        )
ORDER BY dbo_Associates.FirstName;
```

Comment: I strongly suspect that's a *much* more complicated query than you need to provide to demonstrate just this problem. Please simplify it so it *only* deals with the problem you're having.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of all the other stuff your query is doing, what you need to do is calculate `sum(Amount)` in an inner query instead of the outer query.  The structure would be:

```
SELECT a.group_var, a.tot_amount, [other variables you need] 
FROM
    (SELECT group_var, sum(amount) as tot_amount
        FROM sourcetbl
    GROUP BY group_var) as a
INNER JOIN othertbl as b
    ON a.group_var = b.group_var
WHERE tot_amount > 40
    and [whatever] = [whatever value]
```

This is because you can't use WHERE criteria on a calculation you are doing in the same query, so you have to have the calculated sum already available to use in the WHERE.  You can include however many joins and WHERE criteria you need but keep in mind that all WHERE criteria go at the end regardless of which table they reference.